# How to sample efficiently from an inverse Wishart distribution?

Tags: sampling, linear-algebra, cholesky-decomposition, qr-decomposition, inverse-wishart

I am trying to understand the code from [`pybasicbayes`](https://github.com/mattjj/pybasicbayes/blob/master/pybasicbayes/util/stats.py), which defines the following function to sample from an inverse Wishart:

```
def sample_invwishart(S,nu):
    n = S.shape[0]
    chol = np.linalg.cholesky(S)
    x = np.random.randn(nu,n)
    R = np.linalg.qr(x,'r')
    T = scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(R.T,chol.T,lower=True).T
    return T @ T.T
```

I am trying to understand how this works, i.e. why does it actually return random variables with the desired distribution.

Let's say I was trying to sample a Wishart distribution (i.e. the inverse of what is being sampled here). I would do the following. I would let `chol_inv` be the inverse of the cholesky decomposition of $S$, which is $n \times n$. Then, I would consider `chol_inv @ x.t`, would would give me an $n \times \nu$ matrix where each column is an idd draw from a mean-zero multivariate Gaussian in $n$ dimensions with covariance $S^{-1}$. So, finally, to sample the Wishart distribution, I would return `chol_inv @ x.T @  x @ chol_inv.T`, which would return the desired $n \times n$ matrix.

So, I know that one approach that would give us a sample from an inverse Wishart would be to return `np.linalg.inv(chol_inv @ x.T @ x @ chol_inv.T)`, but I can see why this approach may not be desirable, because it would involve taking an inverse twice.

As I understand it, here is what the code I'm trying to understand is doing in math.

We consider the matrix $T$, which is an $n \times \nu$ matrix that satisfies the equation `T @ R = chol`. We know that $R$ is a $\nu \times n$ matrix that satisfies $Q R = X$, where $Q$ is a $\nu \times \nu$ orthogonal matrix and $R$ is a $\nu \times n$ upper triangular matrix.

Now, we could instead consider $T' := T Q.T$ because `T' @ T'.T = T @ Q.T @ Q @ T.T = T @ T.T`, i.e. using $T'$ instead of $T$ would result in the same return. This transformation is meaningful because `chol = T @ R = T @ Q.T @ Q @ R = T' @ x`.

If we are in the setting where $\nu = n$ and so `x` is square and invertible, the result holds immediately. But what if we are in the setting where $\nu \geq n$? I guess this holds using pseudo-inverses?

But still, I don't quite understand

- why is this approach more computationally efficient
- how would anyone of thought of this
- is this a general trick? like could similar approaches be used in other settings?

Comment: If $nxν$ is supposed to be $n \times v$ then in LaTeX you can use `$n \times v$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a huge difference in computational complexity.  Your approach has five $\Omega(n^3)$ operations (three multiplications and two inverses) and the code has four (computing `chol`, `R`, `T` and the return value), but the QR decomposition is 2-3 times slower than any of the others.   For large $\nu$, both the QR decomposition and the formation of $X^TX$ will be $\Omega(\nu n^2)$.  It's going to be within a factor of two or so in operation count, and for large $n$ or $\nu$ the actual times will be dominated by getting numbers on and off the chip.

The code is a bit more computationally stable, because it doesn't have to form $X^TX$, which is the place where the most potential rounding happens.  That's probably not a big issue with modern floating point, but it might matter if you're doing single precision on a GPU or something.

The reason you'd think of this is that computational linear algebra folk (at least in statistics) think of everything in terms of triangular decompositions rather than inverses -- partly because the increased stability used to matter a lot.   And yes, it's a general trick: rather than forming and inverting $X^TX$ you can pretty often work with a triangular decomposition of $X$. That's how linear regression is often done: work with a QR decomposition of $X$ and solve the triangular linear system $R=Q^TY$ rather than inverting $X^TX$.